# Data de Hoje Moments.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estou utilizando o Moment.js com o seguinte código, e nele é para gerar a data de vencimento todo o mês de acordo com a data selecionada, porém quando seleciono a data de hoje, aparece escrito ***Hoje ás 00:00*** e não *28/04/2018*, como corrigir esse erro?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++){
var minhaData = moment(ParcelaVencimento, "YYYY/M/D h:m").add('months', $i);

    ParcelaVencimento1 =  minhaData.calendar();

    var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha'+cont+'">    <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="apagar('+cont+');"> X </button></td>      <td> <input type="hidden" name="cont[]" value="'+cont+'">'+cont+'</td>   <td> <input type="text" name="ParcelaVencimento1[]" value="'+ParcelaVencimento1+'"></td>  </tr>'
```

Data

Hoje às 00:00

28/05/2018

28/06/2018

28/07/2018

Answer (score 0):

Correto é utilizar o método [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) em vez de [`calendar()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/). Outro ponto a se notar, é que o método `add()` [está recebendo parâmetros em formato que foi descontinuado](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/add-inverted-param/), em vez de `add('months', $i)` use `add($i, 'months')`

#### Exemplo funcionando

```js
var ParcelaVencimento = '2018-04-01';
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
  var minhaData = moment(ParcelaVencimento).add($i, 'months');
  console.log(minhaData.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```